# How to find the default values for all the optional srun and sbatch parameters?

Tags: slurm

The question title pretty much says it all.

---

As an example, the `--mem` parameter for `srun` is optional (or at least this is the case for the SLURM instance I have access to).  I would like to know the value for this option that would have the same effect as not specifying the option at all.  (I realize that this particular default may depend on the values of other parameters passed to `srun`, such as the partition, etc.)

Ditto for all the other optional `srun` and `sbatch` parameters.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By default, *--mem* gets ***DefMemPerNode***. 
You can check that value using the command:

> scontrol show config

If it is not defined, its default values will be 0 and it means that the job will be given all the memory of the node.

You can have the other default values from the [FAQ](https://slurm.schedmd.com/srun.html).

Comment: Thanks!  FWIW, when I run `scontrol show config | grep Def`, I only see `DefMemPerCPU`.  Is that what you meant?

Comment: Actually, I just noticed that the docs for `srun` also refer to `DefMemPerNode`; it must be a typo.

Comment: Sorry, I was wrong.  The docs for `srun` mention *both* `DefMemPerNode` and `DefMemPerCPU`.  I don't understand why, when I run `scontrol show config`, I see only the latter.

Comment: I think it depends on whether Slurm is configured to share nodes (in which case `DefMemPerCPU` makes sense) or not (then `DefMemPerNode` makes sense). Check which `select`  plugin is used (`linear` or `cons_res`)

Comment: FYI `scontrol show partition` will show the partition specific configuration for all partitions.